# unable to connect with ssh key in terraform aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have created ssh_key by

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "example@example.com" -f terraform_ec2_key`

and put that `terraform_ec2_key` in my terraform file  and it looks like this

```
provider "aws" {
 region = "us-west-2"
}



resource "aws_key_pair" "terraform_ec2_key" {
  key_name = "terraform_ec2_key"
  public_key = "${file("terraform_ec2_key.pub")}"
  
}

resource "aws_instance" "myfirst" {
  ami = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = aws_key_pair.terraform_ec2_key.key_name
  tags = {   
     name = "terraformec2"
  }
}
```

and when i did `terraform apply`  command it was apllied succesfully and the instance was created but when i connect to the instance using connect command provided by aws

`ssh -i terraform_ec2_key ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

I am getting  `ubuntu@ec2-54-202-8-184.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).`
Here what I have tried `chmod 400 terraform_ec2_key` but not working also open port `22` from inbound rule but still i am getting same error is there anything am I missing?

Comment: Change `public_key = "${file("terraform_ec2_key.pub")}"` to `public_key = file("terraform_ec2_key.pub")` and see if that helps.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Probably your real code is different than in the question and/or you are making some mistakes not described in the question.

Comment: Also what exactly is `ami-830c94e3` for? Ubuntu, are you sure?

Comment: fixed just checked the ami id was wrong

Comment: As I suspected. Anyway, I will make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The code is perfectly fine in itself. The issue was caused by **wrong** `ami-id`. Instead of `ubuntu` AMI, other was used, for example, `amazon linux 2`. This will result in the `Permission denied (publickey)` as `amazon linux 2` uses `ec2-user` user, not `ubuntu.